# How to combine two list in a specific order, i have two list

Tags: python, arrays, list, merge

i am trying to combine two list in a specific order
how?

```
list_1=[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9],[11,12,13,14],]
list_2=[[5],[10],[15]]
answer=[]
for numbers in list_1:
    answer.append(numbers)
    for j in range(1):
        answer.append(list_2[i+j])
    i += j+1`
```

my_output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [15]]
```

expected output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: so you have to append list2 elements to list1 on same index?

Comment: yes the o/p should be = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
instead i am getting [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6, 7, 8, 9], [10], [11, 12, 13, 14], [15]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list(a + b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2))
```

Comment: Can you show how to print the output plz?

Comment: `print(list(a + b for a, b in zip(list_1, list_2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code snippet to combine your 2 lists: -

```
list_1=[[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9],[11,12,13,14],]
list_2=[[5],[10],[15]]

for tup in enumerate(list_1):
    key,value = tup
    b = None
    for val in list_2[key]:
        b = val
    list_1[key].append(b)
print(list_1)
```

It is returning your expected output as : -
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]